# Clean install phpBB and import data

Tags: import, export, phpbb, phpbb3

I need to update an old forum made in phpBB from version 3.0.11 to the new / stable version 3.2.2.

It is the first time that I put my hand at phpBB.

Making an update step by step is complicated: move from 3.0.11 to 3.0.14 ... from 3.0.14 to 3.1.x ... and from 3.1.x to 3.2.2.

So I thought: can I make a clean install of 3.2.2 and import everything I need (posts / forum / users / ALLINEED)?

Do you know any plugins that do this? maybe phpBB itself does it? Or maybe I just need to export the tables from mysql?
can you advise me something?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no plugin to do it, but there is a process to upgrade from 3.0 to 3.2. Your forum will be as clean as a fresh install.

The more secured solution is to begin by upgrading from 3.0.11 to 3.0.14 for security reasons.

When you can stop your forum during one or two hours, stop it and upgrade directly from 3.0 to 3.2. You don’t need to upgrade to 3.1 then to 3.2.

All explanations are provided in [upgrade documentation from 3.0 to 3.2](https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.2/ug/upgradeguide/upgrade3/)

Do not forget any step! After step3, I advise you to restore the 3.0.11 forum on a local machine or another server to be sure that your backup files are not corrupted. (Yes, it could happen during a download.)

I did it a lot of time. It works fine. One hour to do it cautiously and slowly (+ download and upload time).